# How to add list of objects to useState([]) in react?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to add [{}, {}, {} ] to useState([])

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const fetchMessage = (fetched_messages) => {
  if (fetched_messages) {
    setMessages([...messages, fetched_messages]);
  }
};
//fetched_messages = [{},{},{},{}]
```

But the result was messages = [[{}, {}, {}, {}]].

So I tried like this

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

const fetchMessage = (fetched_messages) => {
  if (fetched_messages) {
    var i
    for (i=0; i<fetched_messages.length; i++) {
        setMessages([...messages, fetched_messages[i]])
    }
  }
}
```

But messages was empty.

Could anyone tell me why this happened and how to fix it

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fetched_messages` is an array, and the stateful `messages` is also an array. To set the state properly, do:

```
setMessages(messages.concat(fetched_messages));
```

or

```
setMessages([...messages, ...fetched_messages]);
```

> why this happened

In your first code, it's because you're putting the response array as an item in the larger array:

```
const fetched_messages = [{}, {}];
setMessages([...messages, fetched_messages])
// results in
setMessages([...messages, [{}, {}]])
// if messages is an empty array to start with:
setMessages([             [{}, {}]])
setMessages([[{}, {}]])
```

which isn't what you want.

In your second code, it's because the `messages` array variable *does not change* when you call `setMessages` - the state variable is an immutable `const`, so only the final `setMessages` call results in changes that are visible the next render.

If `fetchMessage` happens to occur only once, on mount, then you don't need to use the existing state at all, just set the new state to the response array:

```
setMessages(fetched_messages);
```